# AngularJS - access DOM element from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive with a templateURL:

```
function myDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element[0].style.height = $(window).height() + 'px';
    },
    templateUrl: chrome.extension.getURL('./templates/hn_feed_tpl.html')
  }
}
```

In my html, I insert the directive like this:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

And the template loaded is very simple:

```
<div class="myDiv">
// some code here
</div>
```

I'd like to access the `.myDiv` div from the directive code to adjust its height. however when I try to adjust it using `element[0]` the element selected is `<my-directive></my-directive>`. How can I access the `.myDiv` div?

Many thanks

Comment: element.children()[0].style.height = $(window).height() + 'px', or even better: element.children().eq(0).css('height', $(window).height() + 'px')

Answer (score 0):

As you have set `replace` to `false` your directive renders to

```
<my-directive>
  <div class="myDiv">
  // some code here
  </div>
</my-directive>
```

which results in `element` pointing to the `my-directive` DOM-element.
In this case you need to access the first child of your element e.g.

```
element.children()[0].style.height = whatever
```

Setting `replace` to `true` avoids the wrapping of your template element and simply replaces your directive element with the one defined in your template.
In this case you can directly use `element` instead, as it points to the element defined in your template.

Comment: bare in mind that the replace property in the directive definition is deprecated in 1.3.x

Answer (score -1):

You can select children by class selector:

```
element.children(".myDiv")
```

Comment: oops, you are right... it would be nice feature to have :)